# Cannot find /usr/local/tomcat/bin/setclasspath.sh error in Tomcat 9 JRE 11 container

Tags: java, docker, tomcat9

So as the title says, I am facing the title issue when running `exec env JAVA_OPTS="${JAVA_OPTS}" /usr/local/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh run` in my entrypoint.sh.

I have tried adding `unset $CATALINA_HOME` to my entrypoint, to no avail.

Any suggestions?

Edit: The JAVA_OPTS env variable does not set an options in regards to tomcat itself, but rather the webapp that is being run through Tomcat

Answer (score 0):

The issue seemed to be multiple JRE version being installed in the container.